# Moment of Inertia of a solid hemisphere. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I want to calculate the MOI of a uniform solid hemisphere about

1. Axis passing through its centre of mass (COM) and perpendicular to the circular base.
2. Axis coinciding with any diameter at the circular base.

To proceed with this, I am using the fact that a solid sphere of mass $M$ and radius $R$ has $$I=\frac{2MR^2}{5}$$

Hence by symmetry argument I am getting the same Moment of Inertia in both the above 2 cases which I think is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280782/moment-of-inertia-of-hemisphere) could help you.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas thanks mate, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symmetry argument is correct, this is because say we have full sphere and an axis passing through its center. Breaking it into 2 symmetrical hemispheres means each carries half of the total moment of inertia that is $\frac{1}{5}MR^2$. But its mass is also half of total so its moment of inertia is $\frac{2}{5}MR^2$, as long as it passes through its center of the total sphere.

Comment: thanks for confirming the answer